# pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server

I'm currently working with SQL Server and Python to write a small script to execute some queries. The connection to the SQL Server works; I can fetch results from different tables and print them on the terminal.

When I try to select all data from a specific table and write them into a new table it didn't work.

```
# Import Libs
import re
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime

# Verbindung mit SQL Datenbank herstellen
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=Censored;'
                      'DATABASE=1110_Database;'
                      'UID=Censored;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
                      'WSID=Censored;'
                      'PWD=PASSWORD'
                      )

cursor = conn.cursor()

# SQL-Abfrage
query = ''' 
            SET NOCOUNT ON
            Select Top 10 * 
            INTO [1110_Database].[dbo].[temp4] 
            FROM [1110_Database].[dbo].[Table1]
        '''

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)

results = [ ]
for row in cursor:
    results.append(row)


cursor.close()
conn.close()

# Print Result in Terminal
print(results)
```

When I don't print the results at the end and comment the whole `results = []` block out, it seems to work but the Table temp4 doesn't exist.

When I use the same SQL Query in SQL Server Management Studio it works.

Comment: A query that does a `SELECT ... INTO` isn't going to return any results, so what data are you expecting to be displayed here exactly?

Comment: Also you define a UID and Password but also state the connection is a trusted connection; these are exclusive. Either you are using a trusted connection (Windows authentication) or username and password (SQL Authentication).

Comment: I don' expect to display any Data on the terminal. I want to write the Top 10 rows from the `[Table1]` into `[temp4]`

Comment: Then why are you printing results? I'm guessing you have autocommit off, try adding: , `,autocommit=True` to your connect call

Comment: Or, otherwise, you need `cursor.commit()` before you close the cursor.

Comment: I know this `block` is not perfect

Answer (score 0):

Using the `cursor.commit()` before closing the cursor was the answer.